# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "type") to tuple

Tags: python

I try to make a tuple of the classes loaded from a module

I get this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "type") to tuple
```

Here is the function causing the issue

```
def addModuleClasses(classes,name,prefix):
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[name]):
        if inspect.isclass(obj) and name.startswith(prefix):
            classes=classes+(obj.__class__) <------------------ error
    return classes
```

The idea behind this is to call that function per imported module

```
import bpy
import somemodulename

classes=()
classes = addModuleClasses(classes,"somemodulename","prefix")
register,unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

which would allow me to import modules without caring about new classes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `(x,)` is a one element tuple, `(x)` is just x.

Comment: still it gives me error : RuntimeError: register_class(...):, missing bl_rna attribute from 'type' instance (may not be registered)